# Inheritance: use inherited methods from parent pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm working with some production code, some of which I cannot safely modify (without breaking things). My issue is that it I would like to use a specific method, one of the parameters of which is a pointer to a class. However the class as the parameter does not do what I want it to.

So I wrote a sub-class of that class and am attempting to call the above function, but it still uses the parent class' methods.

I have a MWE below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent 
{
public:
    Parent() {};
    void method() {std::cout<<"in Parent\n";}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() {};
    void method() {std::cout<<"in Child\n";}
};

void secondMethod(Parent* Pptr)
{
    Pptr->method();
}

int main()
{
    Child c = Child();
    Parent* parentPtr = &c;

    c.method();
    parentPtr->method();

    secondMethod(parentPtr);
    secondMethod(&c);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example running this the output is of course:

```
in Child
in Parent
in Parent
in Parent
```

I believe the issue is slicing? Basically I'm casting to the pointer of the parent class, so it is considered as a Parent.

I have seen some ways around this by making methods virtual in the parent class but I don't have that option.

Is there some way to make secondMethod actual use the child's method? Specifically without changing the Parent class OR the secondMethod.

Answer (score 0):

No not really if you aren't able to change the parent class or 'secondMethod'. The constructor of 'secondMethod' defines its parameter as Parent*. Passing a Child* to 'secondMethod' will cause the Child* to be upcast to Parent* and in turn will cause Parent's implementation of 'method' to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change `method` to virtual function, you may can import template to solve your problem.

    `template<typename T>
    void secondMethod(T* Pptr)
    {
        Pptr->method();
    }`

it may can work!!!